# Create a fragment for a form in Thymeleaf (and spring)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

First I created a form in a simple HTML with Thymeleaf and everything was fine. Then moved to step 2 and I relocated my form to a fragment. I called the fragment like this:

```
<div th:insert="~{address::form($(address)}"></div>
```

and the fragment (which is in address.html) is like this:

```
<form th:fragment="form(address)" action="#" th:action="@{/address}" th:object="${address}" method="post">
   
<label>Street<label><span><input type="text" th:field="*{street}"></span>
<label>County:</label>
  <span>
    <select  th:field="*{county}">
            <option th:each="s : ${countyList}" th:value="${s.value}" th:text="${s.text}"></option>
    </select>
  </span>
...
```

but this is not working and it's throwing:
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'street' available as request attribute*

Please help with how to move an entire form into a Thymeleaf fragment? Also please add ideas for combos, so I can get their list from the model bean. Thank you!

PS the controller looks like this for now (add and edit ) buti will work to make it 1 function instead:

```
    @GetMapping(value="/address")
    public String newAddress(AddressModel address, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("address", address);
        model.addAttribute("countyList", countyService.listCombo());      
        ...
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/address/{id}")
    public String editAddress(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        AddressModel address = addressService.load(id);
        model.addAttribute("address", address);
        model.addAttribute("countyList", countyService.listCombo());
        ...
        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the controller as well? Looks like you are not satisfying all dependencies that the fragment has.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was coming from an unexpected direction. I have put 2 fragments address::form (for creating the form) and address::list (for showing a list of addresses) in the same file and somehow, for some yet unknown reason these 2 fragments are not working fine when in the same file. And the error was not very helpful. But as soon as I put them in 2 separate files like this: addressForm::form and addressList::list everything was ok. Interesting that if I keep the fragments in the same file but swap the order in which they are defined I can render the page  correctly but I still get the error in the logs. Strange things.